# NCover 1.5.8 with Moles/Pex and NUnit

Tags: nunit, moles, pex, ncover

I'm having trouble getting the following to work together.

- NCover 1.5.8 (the version shipped with TestDriven.NET)
- NUnit 2.5 (the version shipped with TestDriven.NET)
- Moles and Pex

I'm using Windows 7 x64 with a .NET 4.0 Pex and Moles test library

I have tried to follow tips from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885612/ncover-support-with-moles) similar question (about getting Moles to work with MSTest) and related links.  I did manage to get Moles and NUnit to work together thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942042/1077279), but I cannot get it to work with NCover.

Here's a batch file.

```
:: Some paths
:: ==========
set NCoverPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NCover\1.5.8
set NUnitPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NUnit\2.5
set MolesPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin

:: Some environment variables
:: ==========================
::  (I've tried every combination I can think of here...)
set ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting=EnableV2Profiler
set COMPLUS_ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting=EnableV2Profiler   
set COR_PROFILER={3FB1CC1E-1C17-4A37-9C18-BF3DB8F10E46}
set CLRMONITOR_EXTERNAL_PROFILERS={3FB1CC1E-1C17-4A37-9C18-BF3DB8F10E46}
:: (Note 3FB1CC1E-1C17-4A37-9C18-BF3DB8F10E46 is the CLSID of NCoverLib.dll 1.5.8.
:: Use {9721F7EB-5F92-447c-9F75-79278052B7BA} instead for NCover 3.x or later)

:: Call NCover
:: ===========
:: Here is the main call to NCover/Moles.Runner/NUnit-Console 

"%NCoverPath%\ncover.console.exe" ^
  //pm moles.runner.exe ^
  //ea "moles.runner;mscorlib.Moles" ^
  //reg ^
    "%MolesPath%\moles.runner.exe" "Pex.Tests.dll" ^
      /runner:"%NUnitPath%\NUnit-console.exe"
```

And this is the output I get:

```
NCover.Console v1.5.8 - Code Coverage Analysis for .NET - http://ncover.org
Copyright (c) 2004-2006 Peter Waldschmidt

Command: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.runner.exe
Command Args: ".\Pex.Tests.dll" "/runner:C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NUnit\2.5\NUnit-console.exe"
Working Directory:
Assemblies:
Coverage Xml: Coverage.Xml
Coverage Log: Coverage.Log

Waiting for profiled application to connect...Microsoft Moles Runner v0.94.51023.0 -- http://research.microsoft.com/moles -- .NET v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

instrumenting...started
NUnit version 2.5.5.10112
Copyright (C) 2002-2009 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.239 ( Net 4.0 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-4.0
.................................
Tests run: 33, Errors: 0, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Connected
Profiled process terminated. Profiler connection not established.
```

It returns error code 1 and my coverage files contain all the test names but with zero coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I found a combination which works.

- The only environment setting necessary is `COMPLUS_ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting=EnableV2Profiler` (setting any of the others mentioned above will cause NCover to fail)
- Use `moles.runner.x86.exe` (instead of `moles.runner.exe`), but use `nunit-console.exe`, not (`nunit-console-x86.exe`)
- You can optionally specify additional args to nunit by using multiple `/args` parameters, e.g., `/args="/domain=None" /args="/xml:MyOutput.xml"`
- Don't forget to copy `Microsoft.Moles.NUnit.dll` to the addins subdirectory of NUnit.

See below for the corrected batch file

```
:: Some paths
:: ==========
set NCoverPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NCover\1.5.8
set NUnitPath=C:\Program Files (x86)\TestDriven.NET 3\NUnit\2.5
set MolesPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin
set PexPath=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Pex\bin

:: Important!
set COMPLUS_ProfAPI_ProfilerCompatibilitySetting=EnableV2Profiler   

:: Here is the main call to NCover/Moles.Runner/NUnit-Console 

"%NCoverPath%\ncover.console.exe" ^
  //pm moles.runner.x86.exe ^
  //ea "moles.runner;mscorlib.Moles" ^
  //reg ^
    "%MolesPath%\moles.runner.x86.exe" "Pex.Tests.dll" ^
      /runner:"%NUnitPath%\NUnit-console.exe"
```

The tests run, the exit code is zero and the coverage files are generated.

Actually, if you don't need the NUnit output files, you can do the same with `pex.x86.exe` as follows:

```
"%NCoverPath%\ncover.console.exe" 
  //pm pex.x86.exe 
  //ea "mscorlib.Moles" 
  //reg ^
    "%PexPath%\pex.x86.exe" "%TestAssemblyPath%\Pex.Tests.dll" /nor /ftf
```

The tests run, the exit code is zero and the coverage files are generated.